# Odoo 8 Tree View limit Parameter not Working

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

Good Day! is the limit parameter/tag not working on a One2many Fields?
I've try the tag but it doesn't work here is my sample code

```
<notebook>
   <page string ="Employee's Attendance">
      <field name="employee_ids" string ="Employee Attendance Information">
           <tree  create = "false" limit="200">
                                    <field name="attendance_status" 
                                    <field name="regular_days_work" />
                                    <field name="absent"/>
                                    <field name="leaves"/>
                                    <field name="tardiness"/>
                                    <field name="straight_duty" 
            </tree>
        </field>
    </page>
</notebook>
```

Please I need some help! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this document you can see there is no limit attribute in tree view in odoo 8

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/reference/views.html#lists

Comment: I've just edit the view_list.js and right now it works for me

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK it doesn't work. Same situation like order by name(or other orderable field) on view.
Perhaps [this](http://bugs.launchpad.net/openerp-web/+bug/1310486) help to you.
Quick solution:
Setting-->Custumization-->Windows action-->edit limit from 80 to 200.
But this setting is effect to all of views.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've just edit the view_list.js but hopefully this must be fix

Comment: Hmm nice job!
Please share the relevant code in an answear, that may help someone in the future.

Comment: in /web/static/src/js/static/js under

Answer (score 0):

Guys thanks and sorry for the late reply as @Döme said this is where i find the javascript code to add the limit of Tree View Parameter in Odoo

in /web/static/src/js/view_list.js

> limit: function () {

```
if (this._limit === undefined) {

    this._limit = (this.options.limit
                  || this.defaults.limit
                  || (this.getParent().action || {}).limit|| 250 /*This value must be change*/); /*default 80*/
```

}

Line code is 115 to 121